# Android app internal test track open/launch button is not available

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-play

I am trying test my first android application using **Internal test track**. As you can see on screenshot, I was able to install it on my device but somehow it doesn't show me **Open** button. Any suggestions?
P.S. During the development I was able to run my application on same device(Samsung Galaxy S7)

`Device Android version: 8.0.0`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was connected with the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
In past the `<data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />` tag was inside of the `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"` tag

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>
```

while now I created two more `activity` tags and moved the `<data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />` tag under the `<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"` tag

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

      <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" 
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
```

The interesting thing was that generated APK with first version of the `AndroidManifest.xml` worked fine on real device(without installing it from Play Store) and I was able to login with facebook through the app. But Play Store doesn't let me open the app and didn't show any warning or error messages.
With second version of the `AndroidManifest.xml` it works fine in both cases.